# Making a computed property customizable through initialization

Tags: swift

I have this class:

```
class ListView: UIView {

    var labels: [UnderlineLabel]

    var listItems: [String] {   return []   }
    var areUnselectable: Bool {   return false   }

...
}
```

I've been using this class up until now by subclassing it and overriding it's computed properties. But now I'm in a situation where I need to use this class, but the only change I need to make is to the `listItems` property (which provides the list of strings, that are turned into `UnderlineLabels`, and can be selected (underlined)). So I'm figuring that rather than subclass `ListView` for such a trivial change, and for a single use-case, it'd be better to refactor the class to enable use by composition.

I've only been able to come up with one solution that allows me to preserve computed property semantics (`listItems` instead of `getListItems()`) and offer customizability to subclasses via overriding, and to instantiators through initializing:

1. Create an additional stored property, perhaps `private let getListItems: (() -> [String])?`
2. Return the result of that, or `[]` if `nil`, by default in `listItems`
3. Allow `getListItems` to be initialized by passing a custom value in `init`

Is this the only way to get the capability I want? And if not, is there a more definitive way of doing this?

Keep in mind that the reason `listItems` is a computed property is to give the list the ability to change during execution.

Comment: Can you post the entire class as you are referring to the strings property, etc but they are not shown in the definition.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth sorry, changed the name to `listItems` for clarity, for the purposes of this question, and wrote the question using `strings` out of habit. edited it

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably end up doing

```
class ListView: UIView {
    var labels: [UnderlineLabel]
    var listItems: [String]
    var areUnselectable: Bool {   return false   }

    init(strings: [String] = []) {
       listItems = strings
    }
...
}
```

Your solution works too, but if it's just an array of strings that won't modify, you don't need a block. I hope I understood your problem correctly however. Also, I'm not sure why you need it to be computed.

Comment: made a mistake writing the question, but the reason it needs to be computed is so the list can change

Comment: so you're not returning an empty array, but another variable? because returning an empty array there will not change the list at any times

Answer (score 0):

It's legal to override a stored property with a computed property. So this works:

```
class A {
    var listItems: [String] = []
}

class B: A {
    override var listItems: [String] {
        get { return [] }
        set { /* do nothing */ }
    }
}
```

Notice the empty setter in the subclass. The `listItems` property is mutable, so the computed override needs a setter, even if it does nothing.

For what it's worth, I don't think this is good code.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case `listItems` may be different from one call to the next, which is why it's a computed property. And if your `A`'s `listItems` was changed to a `() -> [String]`, it would have to be called with trailing parentheses, and the same if overriden in `B`. Which is the main reason I want to keep it a computed property -- to preserve the `listItems` semantics vs `getListItems()`